# Is There any solution for addtion related problem

Tags: embedded

8051 Program embedded C Pl tel output in accumulator

```
#include < reg51.h > 
void main (void) 
{ ACC=0x10 ; B=0x20 ; ACC= ACC+B ; }
```

I'm getting 0x40 in ACC instead of 0x30. why?

I was expecting 0x30.

Comment: Please write a better title, and choose proper tags

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question in response to our comments, please. -- Which compiler in what version are you using? What is the command line to compile? Did you look into the generated machine code / assembly? Commonly the compiler uses `ACC` and `B` for its own purpose, and you are fiddling with them... Did you single step through the program with a debugger and/or simulator? Would you mind to add a listing file? Serious compilers have options to generate such.

Answer (score 2):

C is not assembly.  You should not directly access the core registers in C.  The compiler will generate code that uses those registers - necessarily so, and you cannot guarantee it won't generated code that will modify them.  It makes no sense to attempt this, the compiler will defeat your attempts.  Presumably sensible C code such as:

```
unsigned char a = 0x30 ;
unsigned char b = 0x10 ;
a += b ;
```

works as expected?

If you wish to have complete control of core register usage, you will need to use assembly code.